# Javac compilation problem with JUnit and Windows command line

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors

I would like to compile a folder titled tp2 which contains 2 class and 1 class of test using Junit.
This folder contains also jars for junit org.junit_4.13.0.v20200204-1500.jar and jar for harmcrest org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v20180420-1519.jar.

Following this tutorial https://www.codejava.net/testing/how-to-compile-and-run-junit-tests-in-command-line I try the command :

```
javac org.junit_4.13.0.v20200204-1500.jar; org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v20180420-1519.jar;. TestFilm.java
```

And I get this error : error: invalid flag: org.junit_4.13.0.v20200204-1500.jar;

What does that means exactly ?
Also , What is the best way to compile all the .java files in the same time ?

thanks

Comment: `javac -cp .... TestFilm.java`

Comment: @Eugene  Thanks but trying with -cp I have this error : error: invalid flag: org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v20180420-1519.jar;.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have spaces in your classpath. The reason is says "invalid flag" is because of the space - it's treating it as the next parameter, not as part of your classpath.

If you look at your tutorial, they don't have spaces in the classpath:

```
java -cp <junit-jar>;<hamcrest-jar>;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  TestClass1 TestClass2
```

A more "industrial" way to compile all files is to use maven or gradle.